# How should I mark a folder as processed in a script?

Tags: windows, powershell, shared-directory

A script shall process files in a folder on a Windows machine and mark it as done once it is finished in order to not pick it up in the next round of processing.

My tendency is to let the script rename the folder to a different name, like adding "_done".

But on Windows, renaming a folder is not possible if some process has the folder or a file within it open. In this setup, there is a minor chance that some user may have the folder open.

Alternatively I could just write a stamp-file into that folder.

Are there better alternatives? 
Is there a way to force the renaming anyway, in particular when it is on a shared drive or some NAS drive?

Comment: no, you can't force a rename on an in-use file/folder, since that'd screw up whatever's using the folder in the first place.

Comment: Do you need to skip the processing of the folder itself on the next iteration, or just on the files within that folder?

Comment: Need to skip the folder completely. We get folders consecutively named. Renaming is just too convenient from an operational point of view, but as mentioned, having a stamp file would do too, if all else fails.

Comment: When you say "consecutively named", do you mean that each one is numbered sequentially?

Comment: @Taegost: yes indeed.

Comment: How about copying the folder to another location and process and rename that one? You can always go and cleanup the source folders afterwards or even implement a scheme of what still needs to be deleted next run.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - You still have the limitation that there may be a file lock going on with the source folders, and now you have duplicate data in multiple locations.  If it weren't for that caveat, I'd definitely say that the right way to go is move the folders and their contents into a different folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Put a token file of some sort in each processed folder and skip the folders that contain said file
2. Keep track of the last folder processed and only process ones newer (Either by time stamp or (since they're numbered sequentially), by sequence number)
3. Rename the folder

Since you've already stated that other users may already have the folder/files open, we can rule out #3.

In this situation, I'm in favor of option #1 even though you'll end up with extra files, if someone needs to try and figure out which folders have already been processed, they have a quick, easy method of discerning that with the naked eye, rather than trying to find a counter somewhere in a different file.  It's also a bit less code to write, so less pieces to break.

Option #2 is good in this situation as well (I've used both depending on the circumstances), but I tend to favor it for things that a human wouldn't really need to care about or need to look for very often.

Comment: There's also option 4 - don't use the file-system for synchronization.

Comment: Sure, but there are 2 problems with that: 1) This is a powershell script, and persisting data of this nature in memory can get...  Funky, and will be lost if the session is closed.  2) Since this is a powershell script, my answer relies on the assumption that we need to be able to pick up right where we left off during an earlier run.

Comment: True. But it's still quite easy to use something like a SQL database to hold the information safely, if that's an option. Powershell is a full-fledged language with full access to the .NET framework, after all.

Comment: Sure, that's a possibility too...  Might be overkill for this purpose and wouldn't make the script as portable if they have a similar situation elsewhere, but it is an option that could be considered

Comment: Since no other proposals come forward, I accept your 1. as the correct answer, which we now actually implemented. In fact we do both, we use a token file for automatic operations and at least try to rename the folder for users/admins inspecting the parent folder to immediately get an idea about which data was processed.

Comment: @Harald - That sounds like the best of both worlds in this situation